# Entity Framework Core 2 context and model in separate project to main project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How do i add-migrations into a separate data project??

I've got two projects, a data project with the context and models in and the website project which will use it.   I've linked the two together all fine and dandy, the problem is that when I try and add a migration to the data project with `add-migration initialmigration`, the error

**Unable to create an object of type 'myContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.**

The link has details on how to add the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` but which doesn't work because `UseSqlServer` doesn't exist as a command.   That page does link to the updated version at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#update-main-method-in-programcs which says to put code into `program.cs` Even if I follow the instructions and add it to my data project (along with the associated references) so that I include

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
```

which is what it says to do, but I get the same error message.  So, regardless of whether I include the section of code or not I get the same error message, despite the Microsoft.com page stating that the above code stops the error message I'm getting from appearing.

I've tried putting the context and model into my main project and that generates migrations fine, so the code for those is fine at least.

How do i add-migrations into a separate data project??

Comment: Have you tried to create a class library project, install ef core package and run command from cmd line?

Comment: If you don't have access to UseSqlServer, then you need to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; at the top of your file

Answer (score 0):

`Add-Migration` has a `-Project` parameter.

```
Add-Migration -Project MyProject -Context MyDbContext -Name InitialMigration
```

EDIT: To see all options for a cmdlet (since Package Manager Console is just PowerShell) do

```
Get-Help Add-Migration -Full
```

Answer (score -1):

Your DbContext in class library should look like this:

```
public class ExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public UserProfileDbContext(DbContextOptions<ExampleDbContext > options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Example> Examples{ get; set; }

}
```

And in your Startup you should add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<ExampleDbContext >(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

This is when you are using MS Sql server and have connection string in appsettings.json

Then for example use package manager console for your class library project with EF and it should work.
You should have following nuget packages in you class library project:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Comment: Unrelated to question.